# Добавление файлов в dockerfile из папок, находящихся вне dockerfile

Tags: python, docker

Здравствуйте я новичок в докере и у меня возникла такая проблема. Есть python программа, которую мне нужно перенести в docker, но некоторые файлы программы обращаются к, классам, описанным в других программах, например
`from parsers.common.rabbit import *
from parsers.common.constants import *`.
Структура программы выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мои наработки в Dockerfile (2 варианта) (код в тексте ниже):[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

COPY /home/prilepa/dockerfiles/parsers .

CMD [ "python", "./manager.py"]
```

Главная проблема в том что он не видит папки parsers (ни в одном примере, ни в другом).

```
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder742245107/home/prilepa/dockerfiles/parsers: no such file or directory
```

При этом , если я удаляю слово parsers из самого кода программы и добавлю common в папку с Dockerfile всё работает хорошо (но меня за такое не хвалят). Из этого вопрос. Как сделать этот файл так, чтобы он увидел папку с файлами, которая находится вне папки с Dockerfile-ом. То есть, как "догрузить" в cv_career_habr файлы из common (не добавляя её к cv_career_habr) так, чтобы он не ругался на отсутствие папки parsers (я пробовал делать путь как абсолютным, так и относительным. Создал 2 разные структуры (см.выше) "игрался" с добавлением/удалением папок parsers, но ничего из этого мне не помогло)

Comment: Приведите полную структуру файлов проекта, `Dockerfile`

Comment: [The <src> path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot COPY ../something /something, because the first step of a docker build is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker daemon.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)