# не получается скопировать файл dockerfile

Tags: nginx, docker, dockerfile

Создаю dockerfile который будет копировать nginx.conf и сам сайт в образ. Основа сайта лежит по пути /home/user/prod. Dockerfile и nginx.conf лежат в директории /home/user/web.

Dokerfile простой и содержит

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY /home/user/prod /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80:80
```

Но при сборке контейнера ошибка:

```
Step 3/5 : COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e8af54399767
Step 4/5 : COPY  /home/user/prod /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder504097630/home/user/prod: no such file or directory
```

Использую редактор VIM

Comment: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27068596/4827341), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47012495/4827341)

Comment: идентичные вопросы здесь: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1121558/178576) [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1157358/178576)